# EntityFramework in an Onion archetctured project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

I have a ASP.NET WebAPI 2 project that uses Ninject as IoC. I have a core layer that all my Class Library projects use, and that defines common interfaces.

I have a layer called Repositories where I put my applications repositories, and a layer called DataLayer that defines the different Entity Framework DbContext objects. My Repositories layer has a reference to my DataLayer, and on both the DataLayer and the Repositories Layer I've added EntityFramework.

All repositories classed inside repositories layers are implementing common interfaces from the core, and are injected to the contollers in the API using ninject. At first, when I ran my project and tried to do something against the repository, I got the following error message:

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient'. Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.
```

What I did next is open the app.config file in the repository layer and copy the EntityFramework defenitions to my web.config in the API project:

```
<configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>

<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

but now I get the following error:

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The Entity Framework provider type 'System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer' registered in the application config file for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient' could not be loaded. Make sure that the assembly-qualified name is used and that the assembly is available to the running application. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.
```

I don't think that the solution is including the entity framework in the API references because that would break the separation of concerns - the API shouldn't care what technology is used by the repository to access the data - so that if lets say in a month I would like to change my ORM or even my db, the API should not care what and how I use, as long as it uses the same interfaces.

What is the problem then? I'm new to EF, so I figure I must be missing something...

Answer (score 0):

Your Web Config definitely got messed up somewhere. I would try to delete the .edmx and try to add a new one. This is what my config looks like, not sure if it'll help.

```
 <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>

 <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" /> //did you change this here?
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I don't have edmx file. I'm working db first with reverse engineer. All the code I pasted was automatically generated when I added EF to my class library project.

Answer (score 0):

> the API shouldn't care what technology is used by the repository to access the data

You have one application configuration file and one AppDomain. Both need the relevant Entity Framework configuration and assemblies to be loaded, because code in your DAL requires them.

The *code* of your web API shouldn't care, but the application configuration and hosting environment are separate from that.

Comment: Of course, they get copied to the bin folder as a dependency, but other than that they shouldn't have a reference to EF.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with installing the Entity framework again from Package Manager Console:

```
PM> Install-Package EntityFramework
```

This should solve your problem as the same issues was faced by me once. 
Hope this works out.
Thanks